# Julia DSP: Convolution of discrete signals

Tags: julia, signal-processing, convolution

Here is the [problem](https://github.com/JuliaDSP/DSP.jl/issues/404). I want to write a convolution for two simple signals x[n]=0.2^n*u[n] and h[n]=u[n+2] for some values of n. This is how I implement it:

```
using Plots, DSP

x(n) = if n<0 0 else 0.2^n end
h(n) = if n<-2 0 else 1 end

n = -10:10
conv(h.(n),x.(n))
```

It doesn't work. Here is the error:

```
`float` not defined on abstractly-typed arrays; please convert to a more specific type
```

Any idea how may I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran it fine with a fresh REPL session:

```
julia> using Plots, DSP
[ Info: Precompiling Plots [91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80]
[ Info: Precompiling DSP [717857b8-e6f2-59f4-9121-6e50c889abd2]
        
julia> x(n) = if n<0 0 else 2^n end
x (generic function with 1 method)

julia> h(n) = if n<-2 0 else 1 end
h (generic function with 1 method)

julia> n = -10:10
-10:10

julia> conv(h.(n),x.(n))
41-element Array{Int64,1}:
    0
    0
  
 (etc)
 
 1984
 1920
 1792
 1536
 1024

julia> plot(conv(h.(n),x.(n)))
(plots ok)
```

If you change the 2 in 2^n to a float you need to specify Float64:

```
julia>  x(n) = if n<0 0 else  0.2^n end
x (generic function with 1 method)

julia> conv(h.(n),Float64.(x.(n)))
41-element Array{Float64,1}:
  0.0
  8.458842092382145e-17
  2.5376526277146434e-16
  4.229421046191072e-17
  2.1147105230955362e-16
       
   (etc)
   
  7.997440000004915e-5
  1.597440000003685e-5
  3.1744000002024485e-6
  6.144000000924524e-7
  1.0240000015600833e-7
```

Comment: Yes, it works that way, but if you change 2 to 0.2 it will not! Any idea why? More detail: https://github.com/JuliaDSP/DSP.jl/issues/404

Comment: aha, casting to Float64 works:  conv(h.(n),Float64.(x.(n)))